# Selecting by text with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am mostly familiar with java selenium, and I am new to both JS and Protractor. Lets say I am trying to click an option from a list of options with a common identifier..

```
var options = $('.options');
```

How could I get all elements with that common identifier, and then select one by its text? I can not do driver.findElements like I could in java since there is no reference to driver..

This is what I have tried so far but its not working and I think its due to my inexperience with JS

```
this.selectCompanyCode = function(companyCode) {
    dropDownMenus[0].click();
    var companyCodeOptions = $('[ng-bind-html="companyCode"]');
    companyCodeOptions.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.getText().then(function text() {
            return text === companyCode;
        });
    }).first().click();
};
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? You edited your question after I posted my answer.  I added a `.click()` to my answer just now so my code should do the exact same as your code above, except it does not use `.each()` to iterate through the entire array as that's not necessary.  If not, add a comment what's not working... trying to help you.

Comment: @Gunderson, I did see your answer. Just didnt want to squeeze that code segment into the comment section. I have updated my code on my post to what I have changed it to from your suggestion, however I am now getting a   "cannot read property 'click' of undefined" error.. Could it be how I am trying to pass the companyCode parameter?

Comment: Pretty sure that error has to do with `dropDownMenus[0].click()`;  Usually you would use `.get()` to retrieve an element by index from an ElementArrayFinder (see the link in my answer below).  But also you don't have a reference to dropDownMenus in this function.  Is it a global variable?  If not, it's definitely undefined.  You may also need a return statement from companyCodeOptions.filter.  So `return companyCodeOptions.filter(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all elements with common identifier:  `$$('.options');` That selects all elements with a class of `.options` -- equivalent of `element.all(by.css('.options'))`.  This returns an [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).  Also see [.get()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) for how to choose an element by index from the ElementArrayFinder.

Find by text, you could use `cssContainingText(css, text)`.  For example,
`var loginBtn = element(by.cssContainingText('button.ng-scope', 'Login'));`

But if for some reason those are not providing the expected results, you can use `.filter()` ([docs here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter)) on an ElementArrayFinder to go through the array of elements and find an element based on a condition you specify.  For example,

```
var allOptions = $$('.options');
allOptions.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === 'What you want';
    });
}).first().click();
```

And, although I've never used regular Java Selenium (so I don't know if this is the same), but there is indeed a `browser` reference (and therefore `findElements` function): http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.

Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

Using your code:

```
this.selectCompanyCode = function(companyCode) {
    // where is dropDownMenus defined?  This has function no reference to it.
    dropDownMenus.get(0).click(); // should be this
    var companyCodeOptions = $$('[ng-bind-html="' + companyCode + '"]');
    return companyCodeOptions.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.getText().then(function text() {
            return text === companyCode;
        });
    }).first().click();
};
```

**second edit:** 
Assuming company code is unique, you probably don't need to use filter.  Try this:

```
this.selectCompanyCode = function(companyCode) {
    dropDownMenus.get(0).click();
    var companyCodeOptions = $('[ng-bind-html="' + companyCode + '"]');
    return companyCodeOptions.click();
};
```

Comment: the dropDownMenus is a locator I identified, var dropDownMenus = $$('.select2-choice.ui-select-match.ng-scope'); I see I was missing a return statement, let me give it a whirl. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it is saying companyCodeOptions.filter is not a function

Comment: @Tree55Topz sorry my bad, didn't see companyCodeOptions was defined as a single element, I changed it to use `$$` so it creates an array of elements.  Also see my second edit, not sure it's even necessary to use `filter()` in this case.

Comment: companyCode is actually the identifier that they all share. But the actual text in the dropdown is what Im trying to pass in to click. So for instance, there are 3 options. All share that identifier, ng-bind-html=companyCode. If I were to do a .getText on ng-bind-html=companyCode[0], it would be different from the text I would get from [1]. that actual .getText value is what I am trying to use to select it. So in the html its like <div class="whatever" ng-bind-html="comanyCode">Buddys Pizza</div> .... Buddys Pizza is what I would pass in because that is the text of the option I want

Comment: sorry for the confusion haha >.<

Comment: Oh, then can you just use cssContainingText?  `var companyCodeOptions = element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Buddys Pizza'));`

Comment: Havent tried it that way yet, but I will try. I really wanted to do it the other way though because I think its better practice and it would help me to better understand JS

Answer (score 1):

Use cssContainingText

```
element(by.cssContainingText(".option", "text")).click();
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText